# php mysql out of memory while inserting from excel file

Tags: php, mysql, excel, memory

i'm getting the following error:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\servisa\Excel\reader.php on line 482

i have to read and insert into mysql database from an excel file.
i'm reading a big excel file (13 mb, 9000 rows), putting it into an array, and then i'm generating the insert query while reading the array, is there a way i can do this with less memory?
i know i can set more moemory in php.ini but i don't think it's a good solution. is it?

here's my code, sorry for my horrible english.

```
require_once 'Excel/reader.php';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
$data->read('PAMI/PAMI.XLS');
$arreglo = array(array());
for ($i = 1; $i <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++) 
{
    if ($i == 1)
        continue;

    $nomCompleto = mysql_real_escape_string($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][3]);//str_replace("`", "", str_replace("'", "", $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][3]));
    $parts = explode(" ", $nomCompleto);
    $apellido = array_shift($parts);
    $nombre = implode(" ", $parts);
    $nroBenef = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][1];
    $dni =  $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][5];

    $tipoDni = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][4];
    $sexo = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][8];
    $domicilio = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][9];//mysql_real_escape_string($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][9].' '.$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][10]);

    $date = str_replace('/', '-', $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][6]);
    $fnac = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

    $arreglo[$i][0] = $apellido;
    $arreglo[$i][1] = $nombre;
    $arreglo[$i][2] = $dni;
    $arreglo[$i][3] = $nroBenef;
    $arreglo[$i][4] = $tipoDni;
    $arreglo[$i][5] = $sexo;
    $arreglo[$i][6] = $domicilio;
    $arreglo[$i][7] = $fnac;
}   

$sql ="insert into clientespami (apellido,nombre,dni,nroBeneficiario,tipoDni,sexo,domicilio,fechaNac) values ";
$valuesArr = array();
foreach($arreglo as $fila)
{

    $ape = $fila[0];
    $nom = $fila[1];
    $dni = $fila[2];
    $ben = $fila[3];

    $tipo = $fila[4];
    $sex = $fila[5];
    $domi = $fila[6];
    $nac = $fila[7];

    $valuesArr[] = "('$ape', '$nom', '$dni','$ben','$tipo','$sex','$domi','$nac')";
}

$sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);
//echo $sql;
mysql_query($sql,$conexion);
$cant = mysql_affected_rows();
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and you have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) here.

Comment: Could you convert to CSV and use `LOAD DATA INFILE` instead?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions , I will investigate PDO . CSV suggestion is good, however , I think I 'm getting the error before performing the insert . I think it has to do with the size of the array,

Comment: Loading everything into memory, transforming it into SQL statements, and firing it back out will only work for trivial amounts of data. For anything bigger you really need to stream it in. Loading from CSV is the most efficient, it bypasses PHP completely, plus you don't have to worry about injection problems, the data's handled properly.

Comment: but anyway I have to iterate through all the excel file to convert it to CSV , right?

Comment: Open in Excel, "Save As..." CSV. Could be that easy.

Comment: yes, I know, the problem is that the system is used by people with low skills. but I think I 'll have to teach them to do so, since there is no salvation. Thank you

Comment: If you can transform it in PHP, save it as CSV, and then initiate a `LOAD DATA INFILE` you might find that works best. I know MySQL's bulk import from a file is often surprisingly quick. Hope you can get it to work.

Comment: thanks! i'll try that.